# Does OpenEBS support shared storage?

Tags: openebs

Does OpenEBS provide any kind of storage class that enables shared storage among containers? let's say I have 5 containers that need to access the exact same data. I have several containers doing AI training that need access to a shared image database, so it be like ReadWrite Many way

Comment: Does OpenEBS have any kind of forum or documentation at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Currently OpenEBS is working on block storage.